# Calling a method for another object and class' method, inside a method (Java)

Tags: java

I have a class, LazyAuthor, that stores information about an author and can have a 'rival' (another object of the same class) set for it, and various methods cause them to interact with each other. The LazyAuthor class also relies on another class Book which stores details of the book's title, etc.

I am trying to set up a method rivalsLastTitle that returns the title (from the corresponding Book object) for the rival's last book. I have written this as:

```
public String rivalsLastTitle(){
    return currentRival.getLastBook().getTitle();
}
```

where the corresponding methods I've called are

```
public Book getLastBook(){
    return lastBook;
}
```

from the LazyAuthor class and

```
public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}
```

from the Book class. currentRival is an object of the LazyAuthor class.

However this is returning a null value so clearly my syntax is wrong. I'm not sure how to write this code in order for it to return the title of the rival's lastBook object. I believe I may be overcomplicating the instruction for the return statement but I have seen multiple method calls like this work before.

Any help would be appreciated, I would be happy to share other parts of the code if that's useful. Thank you

edit: Here is the code for the whole LazyAuthor class. Apologies for length:

```
// fields (data members) go here
private int currentMoney, newMoney;
private String authorName, name;
private Book lastBook, bestBook, rLastBook, newBook, newLastBook,newBestBook, nextBook;
private LazyAuthor currentRival, newRival;
private boolean happy, jealous, lol;

// methods go here

public LazyAuthor(String name){
    authorName = name;
    currentMoney = 10000;
}

//set methods
public void setLastBook(Book newLastBook){
    lastBook = newLastBook; 
}

public void setBestBook(Book newBestBook){
    bestBook = newBestBook;
}

public void setRival(LazyAuthor newRival){
    newRival = currentRival;
}


public void setMoney(int newMoney){
    newMoney = currentMoney;
}

public void setName(String name){
    name = authorName;
}

//get methods
public Book getLastBook(){
    return lastBook;
}

public Book getBestBook(){
    return bestBook;
}

public int getMoney(){
    return currentMoney;
}

public String getName(){
    return authorName;
}

public LazyAuthor getRival(){
    return currentRival;
}

// complex methods

public String lastTitle(){
    return lastBook.getTitle();
}

public String bestTitle(){
    return bestBook.getTitle();
}

public String rivalsLastTitle(){
    rLastBook = currentRival.getLastBook();
    return rLastBook.getTitle();
}

public boolean isHappy(){
    // happy if last book written is their best OR they sold film rights for it
    if(lastBook == bestBook || lastBook.filmRightsAreSold() == true) {
        happy = true; }
    else { 
    happy = false; }

    return happy;
}

public boolean isJealous(){
    // jealous if their rival's last book made more money, but isn't jealous if they managed to sell film rights for their last book
    rLastBook = currentRival.getLastBook();
    if(rLastBook.getValue() > lastBook.getValue() ){
        jealous = true; }
    else {
        jealous = false;}
    if(lastBook == bestBook || lastBook.filmRightsAreSold() == true) {
        jealous = false; }


    return jealous;
}

public boolean laughsAboutRival(){
    // they laugh if their rival didn't sell film rights for their last book or if it made less than their own
    rLastBook = currentRival.getLastBook();
    if(rLastBook.filmRightsAreSold() == false || currentRival.getLastBook().getValue() < lastBook.getValue()) {
        lol = true; }
    else {
        lol = false;}

    return lol;
}

public void buyBackRightsOfLastBook(){
    if(lastBook.filmRightsAreSold() == true && currentMoney >= lastBook.getBuyBackCost() ){
        setMoney(currentMoney - lastBook.getValue() );
        lastBook.buyBackRights(); }

}

public void writeNewBook(Book newBook){
// writes new book only if their last book wasn't their best, and they   didn't sell the rights to it.
    if(lastBook!=bestBook && lastBook.filmRightsAreSold() == false && currentMoney < lastBook.getValue() ){
        lastBook = newBook;
        currentMoney= currentMoney + lastBook.getValue();
    }
}
```

edit 2: having just looked over the code again while editing this post, I seem to have assigned the labels in some of the set methods the wrong way around. I'm editing this now and will see if this fixes the null pointers.

edit 3: this seems to have worked, thank you all for the reassurance that my original syntax was correct and also for clarification on what a null value implies has gone wrong :)

Comment: Add the code for LazyAuthor

Comment: Your syntax is perfect. Therefore, the problem must be in setting the values, which is not part of the code you've shown.

Comment: The problem might be on the book class and how it is title initialized. If there was something wrong on the other classes you would get a null pointer

Comment: In general: if there is a null value being returned, the syntax is _not_ wrong. It is the values that are wrong (or at least, unexpected).

Comment: There's only two plausible null values here, `currentRival` and `lastBook`. To me these both seem like values that could potentially be null (in design), so it might just be worth null checking